# The destination property matches multiple source property hierarchies - SpringBoot, ModelMapping

Tags: java, spring-boot, modelmapper

I am trying to add a list of rented books to my database.

I am using ModelMaper with SpringBoot.

Here is code:

**RentDto.java**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
public class RentDto {

    private Long rentId;

    private Long userId;

    private Long bookId;

    private String userFirstName;

    private String userLastName;

    private String bookTitle;

    private LocalDateTime rentStart;

    private LocalDateTime RentEnd;

}
```

**RentController.java**

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Add Multiple Rents")
@PostMapping("/addMultipleRent")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public void addMultipleRent(@RequestBody List<RentDto> rentDto){
    rentService.addMultipleRents(rentDto);
}
```

**RentService.java**

```
 public void addMultipleRents(List<RentDto> rentDto){
            rentRepository.saveAll(mapRentListDtoToRentList(rentDto));
    }

    //Convert List of books to List of bookDto
    private List<Rent> mapRentListDtoToRentList(List<RentDto> rents) {
        return rents.stream()
                .map(rent -> modelMapper.map(rent, Rent.class))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

I am getting the following error:

```
1) The destination property com.example.library.entity.Rent.setId() matches multiple source property hierarchies:

    com.example.library.dto.RentDto.getRentId()
    com.example.library.dto.RentDto.getUserId()
    com.example.library.dto.RentDto.getBookId()
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I found.

Added this line to my `addMultipleRents()` method.

```
List<Rent> rent = Arrays.asList(modelMapper.map(rentDto, Rent.class));
```

After I added it **RentService.java** looked like this:

```
public void addMultipleRents(List<RentDto> rentDto){
        List<Rent> rent = Arrays.asList(modelMapper.map(rentDto, Rent.class));
            rentRepository.saveAll(rent);
    }
```

I completely deleted method `mapRentListDtoToRentList`.

Answer (score 0):

add an `@Id` annotation to your `rentId` field, sp spring knows which is THE id, that can also used for searching etc:

```java
public class RentDto {

    @Id
    private Long rentId;

    //...
}
```

Comment: Hi, I just posted an answer that worked for me. But I will try your advice as well.